# Change width of the flex columns?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have 2 list columns and in one of the columns i have a list which i am breaking up using CSS to have the data wrap in the next column after a specific height. But if you see the [demo](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/GRRPaPM), you will see there is so much white space between first and second column. I am not sure how can i make it so that the list items take up the white space?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      lists: [{
          text: 'list1'
        },
        {
          text: 'list2'
        },
        {
          text: 'list3'
        },
        {
          text: 'list4'
        },
        {
          text: 'list5'
        },
        {
          text: 'list6'
        },
        {
          text: 'list7'
        },
        {
          text: 'list8'
        },
        {
          text: 'list9'
        },
        {
          text: 'list10'
        },
        {
          text: 'list10'
        },
        {
          text: 'list2'
        },
        {
          text: 'list3'
        },
        {
          text: 'list4'
        },
        {
          text: 'list5'
        },
        {
          text: 'list6'
        },
        {
          text: 'list7'
        },
        {
          text: 'list8'
        },
        {
          text: 'list9'
        },
        {
          text: 'list10'
        },
        {
          text: 'list10'
        },
        {
          text: 'list10'
        },
        {
          text: 'list10'
        },
        {
          text: 'list2'
        },
        {
          text: 'list3'
        },
        {
          text: 'list4'
        },
        {
          text: 'list5'
        },
        {
          text: 'list6'
        },
        {
          text: 'list7'
        },
        {
          text: 'list8'
        },
        {
          text: 'list9'
        },
        {
          text: 'list10'
        },
        {
          text: 'list10'
        },
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.column_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100px;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-layout>
          <v-flex>
            <h2>This is the first Column And there is a lot of space in between.</h2>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex class="column_wrapper">
            <div v-for="list in lists" :key="list">
              <span class="title">{{list.text}}</span>
            </div>
            </h1>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Right now, it seems like the list grows only to the right. How can i make it grow or shrink evenly to both sides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple. Add shrink property to the block which you want to take less space:

```
    <v-flex shrink>
     <h2>This is the first Column And there is a lot of space in between.</h2>
    </v-flex>
```

And grow to the one you want to take more:

```
    <v-flex class="column_wrapper" grow>
        <div v-for="list in lists" :key="list">
        <span class="title">{{list.text}}</span>
      </div>    
      </h1>         
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the grow and shrink dynamic? now if i remove the list items, then i have all the list items in one place and now there is space on the right side.

Comment: Or how about if i want to add the flex or shrink class based on array length, So if list items exceed certain length, we apply grow or shrink and if it doesn't it stays the same?

Comment: oh i figured it out, ternary operators.

Comment: @Somethingwhatever basically `:shrink='someBoolValue'` should work for you, but I think you should be able to solve this with pure css

Answer (score 0):

According to [Vuetify](https://v1.vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/grid), the v-flex adds flex: 1 1 auto; that means that it has flex-grow set to 1, while your .column_wrapper element has not. You can either add width: 100% to your .column_wrapper, set flex-grow: 0 to the v-flex or add a bigger flex-grow to the .column_wrapper.